# Rspec Capybara get port before run first visit method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, capybara

I'm try to run Capybara server before all tests to get server port which I should include in url like 'http://subdomain.domain.au:CURRENT_PORT_NUMBER/'
so

```
# I create new session:
session = Capybara::Session.new(:selenium)
# then I start browser
session.driver.browser
# And try to get port number like some folks suggested
Capybara.current_session.driver.rack_server.port # => nil
# And get nil
```

In my opinion when browser started you should have port number somewere. Or I'm wrong?
I do not want hardcode port number for all requests.
Can anyboady suggest how can I get port to visit my application.

As far as I understand browser it's another process and can be started without local server. Thats make sence only when you query server over network. There should be mechanism to run rack server when 'selenium' test start. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Capybara.default_port` to get/set the port.

Comment: Is it possible to get value choosen port without configuring it manualy?

Comment: Yes, the above code will return the port even if you don't configure it.

Comment: Ok it's need to check cause I already hardcode Capybara.server_port = 9876 and thats solve my problem.